# ndb fetch_page does not return next cursor after delete

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have basic paging implemented for my app where I show 5 items(ndb.Model) at a time. I query them  using code below,

```
  fetched_resutls,next_cursor, more = Content.query(Content.user_email == user_email).order(-Content.sent_time).fetch_page(5, start_cursor=cursor)
```

When user deletes an item, I use below code to delete an item and requery first five items. I pass an empty cursor to delete. During this re-query, next_cursor is None although there are more items. Can anybody explain why?

```
        contentIntId = int(content_id)
        content = Content.get_by_id(contentIntId)
        content.key.delete()
        fetched_results, next_cursor = Content.find_by_email(user.email(), cursor)
```

If I do a plain re-query without delete preceeding it, then I do get the next cursor.

-----Edit 1-------

**Code for find_by_email**

```
  def find_by_email(cls, user_email, cursor):
      fetched_resutls,next_cursor, more = Content.query(Content.user_email == user_email).order(-Content.sent_time).fetch_page(5, start_cursor=cursor)
      li = []
      ep = None
      for p in fetched_resutls:
          ep = p.to_dict()
          ep['id'] = str(p.key.id())
          li.append(ep)

      next_bookmark = None
      if more:
        next_bookmark = next_cursor.to_websafe_string()
      return li, next_bookmark
```

**Sequence of events,**

1. I first do a plain query using empty cursor. I get 5 items with a
   cursor back.
2. User deletes an item from the list and I re-query first
   five items with an empty cursor. Although, I get items, I don't get a cursor back.

Comment: Have you tried this on the first page, too? Does this happen there (if your *start*-cursor is None)?

Comment: Please show the code inside find_by_email(). That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: @ T. Steinrücken One the first page it works fine. I get 5 items and cursor back. But when I query after delete, although I get 5 items..i get no cursor back.

Comment: @Guido van Rossum..I have now added body of the method in the edit.

Comment: Still too ague, sorry. What is in your db. Show all the code together. Strip things that dont affect the problem

Comment: @Guido...Sorry, I will soon create a standalone testcase for this. I believe its a bug. For now, I am using a workaround where I query the items before I delete. Then, I get a next cursor as expected. If I delete and then query, I don't get the next cursor as expected.